# spring integration jmx connection issue with weblogic 12.1.2

Tags: spring, spring-integration, weblogic12c

We have spring integration app where we have enabled the JMX by using following config but somehow, i dont see those JMX beans or any spring beans in jConsole when i connect to Weblogic. What we are doing wrong? I do see that other weblogic specific jmx beans are visible in jconsole but nothing from spring.

```
<context:mbean-export registration="ignoreExisting"/>
<context:mbean-server/>
<int-jmx:mbean-export default-domain="testApp"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is here:

```
* <p>By default, {@code MBeanServerFactoryBean} will always create
* a new {@code MBeanServer} even if one is already running. To have
* the {@code MBeanServerFactoryBean} attempt to locate a running
* {@code MBeanServer} first, set the value of the
* "locateExistingServerIfPossible" property to "true".
```

Therefore the application context is supplied with the `newMBeanServer` instead of that one which already exist in the environment.

**UPDATE**

The Namespace support doesn't provide that option, though. Therefore consider to use generic bean definition:

```
<bean id="mbeanServer" class="org.springframework.jmx.support.MBeanServerFactoryBean"
    p:locateExistingServerIfPossible="true" />
```

Comment: Yes, but I cannot find out how to set this property "locateExistingServerIfPossible" to look for existing MBean server via following namespace config  <context:mbean-export registration="ignoreExisting"/>
<context:mbean-server/>
<int-jmx:mbean-export default-domain="testApp"/>

Comment: So when this property is true, does it look for specefic port? Since I changed the port on weblogic, I want to make sure it discover existing mbean server on specific port.

Comment: I think i figured out. Thank you Artem for providing that "MBeanServerFactoryBean" details, that helps and works out of the box